# Division by subtration - dividing the remainder by subtration?

Tags: java, c++, c, math

We can divide a number by subtraction and stop at the remainder as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186421/how-to-divide-using-addition-or-subtraction).

But how do we continue to divide the remainder by subtraction ? I looked on google and could not find such answers. They don't go beyond the remainder.

For example, lets say we have

```
7/3.
7-3 = 4
4-3 = 1
```

So, we have `2 & (1/3)`. How do we do the `1/3` 
division using only subtraction or addition ?

**REPEAT - 
Please note that I dont want to use multiplication or division operators to do this.**

Comment: You have the divisor.  Looking at the last result, think how you might create 1/3 using the divisor and the last result.

Comment: What do you mean by "1/3 division"? What do you expect the result of such division to be? You got your quotient, and your remainder - what more do you need?

Comment: If you're trying to do integer division rather than floating point division, than you can just truncate the remainder

Comment: To continue dividing, you'd have to append additional digits to the right of the remainder.  This is what you'd do to produce a floating-point result, but it gets messy and you have to consider things *very* carefully.

Comment: Hint:  Consider how you'd produce a result with a decimal fraction using old-fashioned long division.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Please note that I dont want to use multiplication or division operators to do this.

Comment: @HotLicks - Please note that I dont want to use multiplication or division operators to do this.

Comment: -1 for repeating sheeplishly "no multiplication operaotrs" when even a 10 year old could figure out how to replace multiplication of integers by addition.

Comment: @Ingo - Repeated addition 1/10 times ? How do i do that ? Divide 1 by 3 using only plus and minus operators. The result can be a float or a double.

Comment: Look at @jh314s answer. Besides, you schould have learned in school how to do to this division. 1/3 = (10/3)/10 = (100/3)/100 = (1000/3)/1000, where the division by powers of 10 is just adding so many 0 before the result and finally put "0." in front.

Comment: @Ingo - I think I mentioned that / or * is NOT to be used. If you prefer German - Ich glaube, ich erwähnte, dass / oder * NICHT verwendet werden soll.

Comment: Did you read that I said " where the division by powers of 10 is just adding so many 0 before the result"? And how to do 10/3 with subtraction, you already know.

Comment: @Ingo - oh ! and how do you "add" 0 before the result ? Its not a pen and paper game where you just drop some 0's before the result. It is also not like a string result to which you pre-pend 0's. How do you do it LIKE a computer ? 10/3 is easy in terms of subtraction.

Comment: @mathmongol Why is a string as result bad? Once you finish you can convert it to double or whatever. And, BTW computers do exactly that in binary by shifiting right logical (i.e. a 0 is shifted in). If you wnat it in decimal (as most posters here seem to assume), you'll need a string or some other "decimal" data type that supports shifting left or right. (i.e. appending a 0 at the end or after the decimal point.

Comment: Or, @mathmongol, if you prefer it in german: "Habe den Mut, dich des eigenen Verstandes zu bedienen."

Comment: @Ingo - Ich habe eine Menge Mut, genug, um mit denen, die es fehlt teilen. :)

Comment: @mathmongol - I've several times written the microcode for doing division in binary.  It's done entirely with addition/subtraction -- extension to decimal is trivial.  The clever way to do it is with a "non-restoring" divide, where when you subtract and get a negative you don't add the value back but instead continue, carrying some extra state.  I don't recall the details (it's been 30-odd years) but you might be able to look it up.  (Though I'm not sure how well the "non-restoring" technique carries over to decimal.)

Comment: (Does it need to be done in decimal, or can you do it in binary?)

Comment: Once again, think about how you'd do long division to achieve a fractional result.  It's the *exact* same process.

Comment: (Do you know how to do [long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division)?  If not, look it up (there are at least a dozen good references if you Google it) and learn it first.  Practice on paper until you understand it.)

Answer (score 6):

You can get additional "digits", up to any arbitrary precision (in any base you desire, I'll use base 10 for simplicity but if you're trying to implement an algorithm you'll probably choose base 2)

```
1) Perform division as you've illustrated, giving you a quotient (Q=2), a divisor (D=3), and a remainder (R=1)
2) If R=0, you're done
3) Multiply R by your base (10, R now =10)
4) Perform division by subtraction again to find R/D (10/3 = 3+1/3). 
5) Divide the resulting quotient by your base (3/10 = 0.3) and add this to what you got from step 1 (now your result is 2.3)
6) Repeat from step 2, dividing the new remainder (1) by 10 again
```

While it sounds an awful lot like I just said division quite a few times, we're dividing by your base. I used 10 for simplicity, but you'd really use base 2, so step 3 is really a left shift (by 1 bit every time) and step 5 is really a right shift (by 1 bit the first time through, 2 bits the second, and so on).

```
7/3.
7-3 = 4
4-3 = 1
7/3 = 2 R 1

1*10 = 10
10-3 = 7
7-3 = 4
4-3 = 1
10/3 = 3 R 1
7/3 = 2 + 3/10 R 1
7/3 = 2.3 R 1

1*10 = 10
10-3 = 7
7-3 = 4
4-3 = 1
10/3 = 3 R 1
7/3 = 2.3 + 3/100 R 1
7/3 = 2.33 R 1
```

And so on until you reach any arbitrary precision.

Comment: Please note that I dont want to use multiplication or division operators to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep going to get decimal digits, multiply the remainder by a power of 10.

E.g. if you want 2.333, then you can multiply remainder by 1000, and then repeat the algorithm.

Comment: This would have been my answer!!

Comment: Please note that I dont want to use multiplication or division operators to do this.

Comment: So what, @mathmongol? We assume you can figure out for yourself how to multiply by 1000 without using multiplication operators.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are asking.

If you are asking how to get the end fraction and simply it, let's take a different example.

> ```
> 26 / 6.
> 26 - 6 = 20  count 1
> 20 - 6 = 14  count 2
> 14 - 6 = 8   count 3
> 8 - 6 = 2    count 4
> ```

(In code, this would be accomplished with a for loop)

Afterwards, we would have 4 2/6. To simplify, switch the dividend and divisor:

> 6 / 2.
>      6 - 2 = 4     count 1
>      4 - 2 = 2     count 2
>      2 - 2 = 0     count 3

If this finishes without a remainder, show as 1 over the count.

In pseudo-code:

```
int a = 26;
int b = 6;
int tempb = 6;
int left = 26;
int count = 0;
int count2 = 0;

left = a - b;

for(count; left > b; count++){
       left -= b;
}    

if(left > 0){
    for(count2; tempb > left; count2++){
        tempb -= left;
    }

console.log("The answer is " + count + " and 1/" + count2);
```

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Please note that I dont want to use multiplication or division operators to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete program that uses only + and -, translate to your language of choice:

```
module Q where

infixl 14 `÷` `×`

a × 0 = 0
a × 1 = a
a × n = a + a×(n-1)

data Fraction = F Int [Int]

a ÷ 0 = error "division by zero"
a ÷ 1 = F a []
0 ÷ n = F 0 []
a ÷ n 
    | a >= n = case (a-n) ÷ n of
                F r xs -> F (r+1) xs
    | otherwise = F 0 (decimals a n)
    where 
        decimals a n  = case (a × 10) ÷ n of   
            F d rest  = (d:rest)

instance Show Fraction where
    show (F n []) = show n
    show (F n xs) = show n ++ "." ++ concatMap show (take 10 xs) 

main _ = println (100 ÷ 3)
```

It is easy to extend this in such a way that the periodic part of the fraction is detected, if any. For this, the decimals should be tuples, where not only the fractional digit itself but also the dividend that gave rise to it is kept.
The printing function could then be adjusted to print infinite fractions like 5.1(43), where 43 would be the periodic part.